# Fourier transform of a correlation function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, stochastic-processes

I need to prove that

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \omega^2 e^{i\omega (t-t')} \langle{x(t) \ x(t')}\rangle \ d\omega \ dt \ dt' =  C \langle{(x'(t)|_{0})^2}\rangle$

where $x(t)$ has to be understood as a probability distribution, $\langle\rangle$ is a thermal average over that distribution and $x'(t)$ is the derivative with respect to $t$. The average can be taken outside the integrals without problem. Also, $\langle{x(t)x(t')}\rangle$ is invariant by time translation meaning it's only a function of $t-t'$.

The derivative is evaluated at $t=0$.

Here is one way I found to do it (I don't care too much about constants) :

$\Big \langle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\omega-\omega') \omega \ \omega'  e^{i\omega t}  e^{-i\omega' t'} {x(t)x(t')} \ d\omega \ d\omega' \ dt \ dt'\Big \rangle$

$=\Big \langle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \delta(\omega-\omega') \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d( e^{i\omega t})}{dt}   x(t)\ dt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d( e^{i\omega' t'})}{dt'} x(t')\ dt' \ d\omega \ d\omega''\Big \rangle$

I integrate by part over $t$ and $t'$ to transfer the derivative on the other function (the boundary term vanishes by some argument) :

$= \Big \langle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \delta(\omega-\omega') \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega t}   x'(t)\ dt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{i\omega' t'} x'(t')\ dt' \ d\omega \ d\omega''\Big \rangle$

Then I integrate over $\omega'$ to get rid of the $\delta(\omega-\omega')$ function.

$= \Big \langle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega (t-t')}   x'(t) x'(t') dt \ dt' \ d\omega\Big \rangle$

Finally, I define $\tau = t-t'$ and $\tau' = t+t'$ and I use the time translation invariance propriety to integrate over $\tau'$. This gives me the desired answer.

$= C' \Big \langle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega\tau}   x'(\tau) x'(-\tau) d\tau \ d\omega\Big \rangle = C \langle{(x'(t)|_{0})^2}\rangle$

My problem is that I get a different answer by doing things in slightly different way. If I first define  $\tau = t-t'$ and $\tau' = t+t'$ and integrate over $\tau'$:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \omega^2 e^{i\omega (t-t')} \langle{x(t) \ x(t')}\rangle \ d\omega \ dt \ dt' = C' \Big \langle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \omega^2 e^{i\omega\tau}   x(\tau) x(-\tau) d\tau \ d\omega'\Big \rangle$

$ = -C' \Big \langle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{d^2( e^{i\omega \tau})}{d\tau^2}   x(\tau) x(-\tau) d\tau \ d\omega'\Big \rangle$

Integrating by part two times I get :

$= -C' \Big \langle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega \tau}  \frac{d^2( x(\tau) x(-\tau))}{d\tau^2}   d\tau \ d\omega'\Big \rangle$

The derivative of the product $x(\tau) x(-\tau)$ will contribute with many terms, namely $x''(\tau) x(-\tau) - 2 x(\tau) x(-\tau) + x(\tau) x''(-\tau)$ and it will lead to a different answer than expected.

Comment: Yes it's mostly a math question but this is the kind of thing often encountered on physics I think

Comment: True  enough, best of luck with it